# Accessing file in Amazon S3 via object url returns AccessDenied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am clicking into my s3 bucket in the Amazon S3 management console and I'm trying to view an object via its url:

[image]

However, I see this:

[image]

Any idea what the error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects in Amazon S3 are **private by default**. This way, other people cannot access your data.

If you wish to access a private Amazon S3 object in the management console, click the **Open** or **Download** button. This will generate a **URL that includes authorization information** that will give you access to the object.

Merely clicking the URL of an object will cause your browser to access the object without authentication. If the object is private, then the request will (correctly) fail. If the object is public, the URL will work (for you and for anyone on the Internet).